# Increase a selected range to a specific row number

Tags: vba, excel

I'm sure this is simple but can't seem to find the answer anywhere on the internet or through the help function.

I have the `Range("AL10939:AN10939")` selected and I want expand the range up so it goes from this row to row "2" inclusive. This will be done frequently with changing numbers of data in the middle so I can't use `selection.End(xlToUp)`

Any thoughts guys/girls?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: So you want `Range("AL2:AN10939")` selected?

Comment: You should watch: [Excel VBA Introduction Part 5 - Selecting Cells (Range, Cells, Activecell, End, Offset)](https://www.youtube.com//watch?v=c8reU-H1PKQ&index=5&list=PLNIs-AWhQzckr8Dgmgb3akx_gFMnpxTN5)

Comment: Using `Range (Cells(Row, Column), Cells(Row, Column))` notation could help you to select a range using row number reference in a simple way.

Comment: I want that range selected but the bottom row will change every time I run the code so it needs to be dynamic.